# how to prove if $a|b$ and $b\neq 0$, then $|a|\leq|b|$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility, absolute-value

where the conditions are:
$a \neq 0$, $b \neq 0$ and $a$ and $b$ are integers.

maybe i'm missing something very basic about the properties of an absolute values.

My approach was to supposed, on the contrary, that |b| >= |a|, but I'm always getting that |b| is indeed >= |a|

could someone help me?

Comment: Are you missing a condition on $b/a$?

Comment: @ADF: Perhaps Draconar means $b\mid a$ (and in the title $|b|\le|a|$), but it certainly has to be cleared up before the question can be answered.

Comment: I re-wrote the conditions. Is it clearer?

Comment: Hint: IF $x$ is an integer and $x\neq 0$ then $|x|\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $a\mid b$, then there is an integer $n$ such that $b=na$, and therefore $|b|=|n||a|$. Since $b\ne 0$, we know that $n\ne 0$, and therefore $|n|$ is a positive integer. Therefore $|n|\ge 1$. If you now multiply this inequality by the right thing, you’ll get the desired result.

Comment: by 'this' inequality you mean $|n| \ge 1$, right?

Comment: @Draconar: I do indeed.

Comment: thank! got it :D hope it is right. Are we allowed to post solutions in here?

Comment: @Draconar: Absolutely. In this case, though, I can just finish the argument, and you can compare that with what you have. Multiplying $|n|\ge 1$ by $|a|$, we get $|b|=|n||a|\ge 1\cdot|a|=|a|$, which is exactly what we wanted to prove.